# Ansible: How to use the file extracted from FIND module?

Tags: ansible

Got stuck with this small thing. I've found a file depending on a pattern, now I want to copy the content of the file to another file. Another file may or may not be empty. So, the entire content in another file should be replaced with the file found. Both the files are present in target machine.

```
- find:
   paths: '/home/usr/Desktop/files/info.txt'
   use_regex: yes
   pattern: (info)
   file_type: file
  register: file_name
 
- copy:
   src: "{{file_name}}"
   dest: /home/usr/Desktop/myinfo/new.txt
   remote_src: yes
```

Here, I want content of **file_name** to be copied in **new.txt**. It's finding the file but not able to copy it since it doesn't have any attribute like 'content' or 'files' which can do the purpose.

Suggest me out with possible ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` will invariably return you a list of files.

If you are sure your `find` will only ever match a single file, you can copy your file getting the first element (so at position `0` in the `files` array) and then get its `path`.

```yaml
- copy:
    src: "{{ file_name.files.0.path }}"
    dest: /home/usr/Desktop/myinfo/new.txt
    remote_src: yes
```

---

For further debugging, you could have done:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ file_name }}"
```

In order to see the structure of the variable `file_name` and correct your playbook.

In your case, this would yield you:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "examined": 0,
        "failed": false,
        "files": [],
        "matched": 0,
        "msg": "/home/usr/Desktop/files/info.txt was skipped as it does not seem to be a valid directory or it cannot be accessed\n"
    }
}
```

Because, well `/home/usr/Desktop/files/info.txt` is not a path, it is a file.

So you should also correct your `find` task:

```yaml
- find:
    paths: '/home/usr/Desktop/files/'
    use_regex: yes
    pattern: (info)
    file_type: file
  register: file_name
```

And this time the debug would yield:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "examined": 1,
        "failed": false,
        "files": [
            {
                "atime": 1593535103.2879748,
                "ctime": 1593535103.2879748,
                "dev": 112,
                "gid": 0,
                "gr_name": "root",
                "inode": 2360831,
                "isblk": false,
                "ischr": false,
                "isdir": false,
                "isfifo": false,
                "isgid": false,
                "islnk": false,
                "isreg": true,
                "issock": false,
                "isuid": false,
                "mode": "0644",
                "mtime": 1593535103.2879748,
                "nlink": 1,
                "path": "/home/usr/Desktop/files/info.txt",
                "pw_name": "root",
                "rgrp": true,
                "roth": true,
                "rusr": true,
                "size": 0,
                "uid": 0,
                "wgrp": false,
                "woth": false,
                "wusr": true,
                "xgrp": false,
                "xoth": false,
                "xusr": false
            }
        ],
        "matched": 1,
        "msg": ""
    }
}
```

And then debugging `file_name.files.0.path`

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ file_name.files.0.path }}"
```

Would yield

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "/home/usr/Desktop/files/info.txt"
}
```

---

This said, and as your question is written, you just don't need a find, you could just do:

```yaml
- copy:
   src: home/usr/Desktop/files/info.txt
   dest: /home/usr/Desktop/myinfo/new.txt
   remote_src: yes
```

Comment: Oh, that's my bad, I didn't mean to add <info.txt> in Find module, while posting here didn't check that. Thanks for that.

Comment: Well, but I want to find a file (from a directory of almost 20 files), then copy the content to another file. Copy module could directly be used if I've only one file which I don't need to find. Maybe there's some other way of doing so? I want to find some features in the file name, select the file if it has those features (for ex, 'id' from file name- userid.txt), then copy that file's content to other file. You got what I'm looking for...?

Comment: then look at the beginning of the answer where I proposed the right `copy` syntax

Comment: Thanks it worked :}  didn't know  (file_name.files.0.path), we can extract files like this. This is great!!

Comment: @Mizkax the most important thing is: you don't have to know it. Maybe you'll remember it in the end, because you will have used `find` so much that it will print in your memory. But you can deduct this debugging the result and analysing the list / dict returned.